# Deleted /var/patch/applied -- Can I recreate it?

Tags: xenserver

I was cleaning out old patches in my Xenserver and accidentally deleted the applied directory in /var/patch. I know which patches have been applied so can I recreate that folder? Is there an example of what was inside of it?

Noob mistake and no backup.